# Regular expression to remove some special chars

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm looking for a regular expression that can remove all the following characters from a string (and Whitespace too):

`~ % & \ ; : " ' , < > ? #`

Can you help me? I'm coding in ActionScript 3.

Comment: can you specify the language you use?

Comment: Oh, sure, sorry: I'm using ActionScript 3

Answer (score 4):

In ActionScript it goes like

```
yourString.replace(/[~%&\\;:"',<>?#\s]/g,"");
```

Same in Perl:

```
$_ = "~ % & \\ ; : \" ' , < > ? #";
s/[~%&\\;:"',<>?#\s]//g;
print; #prints nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[~%&\\;:"',<>?#\s]+
```

Comment: The single- and double-quotes don't need to be escaped, at least in Perl.

Comment: @Quick, removed escapes, I was trying with sed on bash.

Comment: That's fair enough then since the OP has indicated neither a language or an environment. :)

Comment: Hi, thank you, I noticed it doesn't work without adding \g in the end

Comment: @Lotts, yeah, global flag will need it if you need to replace all instances.

Answer (score 1):

removes all whitespaces in `$mystring` using perl, you will need to add the other chars to in order to create your regex

```
$mystring = "...";
$mystring =~ s/\s//g;
```

Comment: How did you know OP uses perl?

Comment: This is a only 1/14th of the required solution. Very nearly a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
with open ('txt.txt', 'r') as fi: # to read ur file 
    tm = fi.read().replace(',', '\n,') # to replace " , " with \n{enter} i.e to new line
    with open ('out_3.txt','w') as z: # to crate new file wher all changes will done or we simply say that to write a new file 
        for j in tm:
            y = re.sub("[0-9 {} <> -,: _\. = +| \/]",'\n' , j)# to remove required
```

regular expression u can change or modified as per requirement as I don't add "?" as regular expression but u can add as -- `y = re.sub("[0-9 {} <> -,: _\.? = +| \/]",'\n' , j)` for more details about re.sub u can read this documentation https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html

```
for gn in y:
    z.write(gn)
```

Comment: import re
with open ('txt.txt', 'r') as fi:
 tm = fi.read().replace(',', '\n,')
 with open ('out_3.txt','w') as z:
  for j in tm:
   y = re.sub("[0-9 {} <> -,: _\. = +| \/]",'\n' , j)
   for gn in y:
    z.write(gn)

Comment: I have tried to help some with formatting, but please check it, you can use 4 space to format code and ' to format in-line code. Please don't leave code in comments.

Comment: StackOverflow does not require perfect English (or I myself would be pretty lost). But you are not seriously unable to do a little better, are you? Some capitalisation, a sprinkle of punctuation, more words which actually exist in English would really improve this post. Please?